# Create Options menu in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-optionsmenu

I have a main activity along with 3 fragments. I am using navigation drawer to select these fragments. I want to edit the overflow menu options in the action bar based on the fragment currently being shown.
For example:
If Fragment A is being shown now, i would like to have Edit,Sign Out and Settings options under the overflow button. If Fragment B is selected now, i should have only Settings there.

I tried to override the onCreateOptionsMenu() in the main activity with a different xml and in the fragment with a different one but it does not help as only the options in main activity are shown.

In Main Activity:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    //return true;
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

In Fragment A:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getActivity().getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu1, menu);
    //return true;
    return true;
}
```

main.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_signout"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="Sign Out"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"/>
</menu>
```

menu1.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_edit"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="Edit Profile"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_signout"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="Sign Out"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"/>    
</menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

Call `setHasOptionsMenu(true)` in your Fragment's `onCreate()`.

> **`public void setHasOptionsMenu (boolean hasMenu)`**
>
> Report that this fragment would like to participate in populating the
>   options menu by receiving a call to onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu,
>   MenuInflater) and related methods.
>
> If `hasMenu` is **true**, the fragment has menu items to contribute.

To hide a particular MenuItem you can call `setVisible(false)` on it in `onPrepareOptionsMenu()`. For example:

```
@Override
public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    //Hides MenuItem action_edit
    menu.getItem(R.id.action_edit).setVisible(false);
}
```

Comment: i called setHasOptions(true) in onCreateView() of my fragment and also set the visibility to false by menu.getItem((R.id.action_edit).setVisible(false) since there was no menu.get(). still edit option is visible.

Comment: it's giving this:The return type is incompatible with Fragment.onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu)

Comment: Sorry, copy and paste fail ;)

Comment: the app crashes now while starting.

Answer (score 0):

To override options menu you should use setHasOtionsMenu(true) and

```
 @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        return false;
    }
```

That's it